# Persist a Model without JPA annotations

Tags: database, spring, jpa, model, spring-data

I'm querying JIRA Issue data using a OSS [JIRA Client](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/).

```
BasicCredentials creds = new BasicCredentials("batman", "pow! pow!");
JiraClient jira = new JiraClient("https://jira.example.com/jira", creds);
SearchResult result = jira.searchIssues("SOME JQL");
List<Issue> = result.issues;
```

Here is the [Issue Class](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/blob/master/src/main/java/net/rcarz/jiraclient/Issue.java). It's not marked as an Entity and it's attributes are not marked for JPA.

What's the fastest way to persist this in to a database?

Comment: Since you are using Spring I'd use Spring JDBCTemplate

Comment: You don't need to use annotations for JPA, you can also declare the mappings in XML if you want. That being said you are probably better of using plain JDBC and storing it with plain SQL.

Comment: Umm... rolling out your own `Issue` entity? Couple it with a declarative mapper like MapStruct/Dozer/Orika and it shouldn't require much effort. I'd not recommend mapping it as an entity using XML directly. You'd be well advised to keep even a minimal mapping layer between your app database structure and an external API, so as to handle API changes more easily

Comment: M.Denium  Angelo I'm curious about a faster way to do this. JDBC is a heavyweight when the Classes already exist. @crizzis Love your answer!